# How to call MongoDB stored JS function using MongoEngine

Tags: javascript, python, mongodb, mongoengine

I have created and saved on JavaScript Function in MongoDB. Now I am using Python-MongoEngine. I am able to query data but now if I wanted to call this Javascript function already saved at database end, How can I call this function and retrive result ?